# Sending an auth response using to Vue JS using Lumen

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, lumen

I'm building a Vue app which is a dynamic menu. Which means the admin can add products to the menu, and those products will be shown on a card component. Because i need to have restricted pages for the admin to add products, i'm using Lumen from Laravel, to have a simple crud api. Although the problem in my situation is: How to handle Authentication through Vue and Lumen

I already read the docs but couldn't figure out how to imply that kind of code in my Vue project.

```php
$app->get('/post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'auth', function (Request $request, $id) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user = $request->user();    
}]);
```

I want to know what the best way is to send a response from Lumen to Vue that lets Vue know that the admin has logged in and can acces for example '/dashboard'

Answer (score 0):

**In lumen app:** create a route for example "api/config" by auth middleware that return base user info.
**In front app:** before start app check response from api/config. if has user info response access to the dashboard.

pay attention to adding auth middleware on all of admin api in lumen.

Comment: If the credentials are right, it generates a JWT Token. I can check in Vue on '/admin' if the token is set. If so it loads the component, otherwise you go back to '/login' with an error. But i'm affraid hackers can manipulate the javascript and access the admin page